# folder and file images not showing in treeview implementation using AxelSoft library in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview

I am trying to implement treeview using [angular-tree-view](https://github.com/axel-zarate/angular-tree-view/blob/master/index.html).

But am not getting icon folder and file icon expandable and collapsible icon

The link doesn't provide image can anybody tell where to add images

I have included treeview.js and css and injecting AXLESOFT in my controller

```
$scope.structure = { folders: [
                        { name: 'Folder 1', files: [{ name: 'img/folder.jpg' }, { name: 'img/folder-closed.png' }], folders: [
                            { name: 'Subfolder 1', files: [{ name: 'Subfile 1.txt' }] },
                            { name: 'Subfolder 2' },
                            { name: 'Subfolder 3' }
                        ]},
                        { name: 'Folder 2' }
                    ], files: [{ name: 'file.png' }, { name: 'preview.png' }]};

                    $scope.options = {
                        onNodeSelect: function (node, breadcrums) {
                            $scope.breadcrums = breadcrums;
                        }
                    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the `$scope.structure`

Comment: @sagar i have used same structure also not working folder icon is not coming

Comment: You should change the structure as per your application.It is just an example structure defined.

Comment: @sagar folder and file image is not coming